# Rcpp Function slower than Rf_eval

Tags: r, rcpp

I have been working on a package that uses Rcpp to apply arbitrary R code over a group of large medical imaging files. I noticed that my Rcpp implementation is considerably slower than the original pure C version. I traced the difference to calling a function via Function, vs the original Rf_eval. My question is why is there a close to 4x performance degradation, and is there a way to speed up the function call to be closer in performance to Rf_eval?

Example:

```
library(Rcpp)                                                                                                                                                          
library(inline)                                                                                                                                                        
library(microbenchmark)                                                                                                                                                

cpp_fun1 <-                                                                                                                                                            
  '                                                                                                                                                                    
Rcpp::List lots_of_calls(Function fun, NumericVector vec){                                                                                                             
  Rcpp::List output(1000);                                                                                                                                             
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){                                                                                                                                       
    output[i] = fun(NumericVector(vec));                                                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                                                                    
  return output;                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                      
'                                                                                                                                                                      

cpp_fun2 <-                                                                                                                                                            
  '                                                                                                                                                                    
Rcpp::List lots_of_calls2(SEXP fun, SEXP env){                                                                                                                         
  Rcpp::List output(1000);                                                                                                                                             
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){                                                                                                                                       
    output[i] = Rf_eval(fun, env);                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                                                    
  return output;                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                      
'                                                                                                                                                                      

lots_of_calls <- cppFunction(cpp_fun1)                                                                                                                                 
lots_of_calls2 <- cppFunction(cpp_fun2)                                                                                                                                

microbenchmark(lots_of_calls(mean, 1:1000),                                                                                                                            
               lots_of_calls2(quote(mean(1:1000)), .GlobalEnv))
```

Results

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
                     lots_of_calls(mean, 1:1000) 38.23032 38.80177 40.84901 39.29197 41.62786 54.07380   100
 lots_of_calls2(quote(mean(1:1000)), .GlobalEnv) 10.53133 10.71938 11.08735 10.83436 11.03759 18.08466   100
```

Comment: Are you aware that you _are a calling an R function from C++_ including all the commensurate overhead when you use `Rcpp::Function` ?  How can you expect this to be faster than just R?

Comment: Moreover, if you think `Rf_eval()` is what suits your needs, why don't you use it?  Rcpp does not prevent you from doing so as the example demonstrates.

Comment: Also, calling `Rf_eval()` directly from a C++ context is dangerous as R errors (ie, C `longjmp`s) will bypass the destructors of C++ objects and leak memory / cause undefined behavior in general. `Rcpp::Function` tries to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I didn't expect calling the R function from c++ to be faster than R, but I didn't expect 4x slow downs. Rf_eval somewhat does the job but it's a hack. To implement apply-like functionality over files the user passed in a quoted function call of a single variable, values were extracted from the files and `install`ed into the global environment. Eval was then called with the quoted call and the global environment. Obviously I want a cleaner/safer approach, just wanted to cut the performance loss down.

Comment: You are free to construct local, specific, somewhat hack-ish solutions to your heart's content. Just understand that we are providing a more general solution with different goals such as robustness.  In that sense, you are simply out of scope with your personal thinking about Rcpp.  That said, I would invite you to work on a PR to cut any slack or fat from Rcpp::Function you may find.  I doubt here is much though.

Comment: I would honestly suggest opting for pre built functions that are called by a map or using a shared library linking approach so that users could supply their own cpp if using r to go over the data is not an option. You may wish to post an example of the problem within code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rcpp` is great because it makes things look absurdly *clean* to the programmer. The cleanliness has a cost in the form of templated responses and a set of assumptions that weigh down the execution time. But, such is the case with a generalized vs. specific code setup.

Take for instance the call route for an [`Rcpp::Function`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/82d8a3a922fc158f2403b233b2ac6861c538d514/inst/include/Rcpp/Function.h). The initial construction and then outside call to a modified version of `Rf_reval` requires a special `Rcpp` specific eval function given in [Rcpp_eval.h](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/82d8a3a922fc158f2403b233b2ac6861c538d514/inst/include/Rcpp/api/meat/Rcpp_eval.h). In turn, this function is wrapped in protections to protect against a function error when calling into R via a [Shield](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/82d8a3a922fc158f2403b233b2ac6861c538d514/inst/include/Rcpp/protection/Shield.h) associated with it. And so on...

In comparison, `Rf_eval` has neither. If it fails, you will be up the creek without a paddle. (Unless, of course, you [implement error catching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485899/is-it-possible-to-catch-error-in-c-for-rf-eval-r) via `R_tryEval` for it.)

With this being said, the best way to speed up the calculation is to simply write everything necessary for the computation in `C++`.

Comment: I like _make[s] things look absurdly clean to the programmer_. I may need to quote that one day :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel by all means, go ahead!

Comment: Thanks @Coatless,

It seems amazing to me that error catching would quadruple the execution time. This function that inspired this question is meant to allow the user to apply arbitrary R code to a group of files, somewhat like bigmemory. So as far as I know doing a complete c++ translation would be impossible. So I suppose the underlying question is still what is the most performant way to implement a general apply with Rcpp and/or the R-C API

Comment: You can sweep arbitrary R functions over data just fine from the R side.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the points made by @coatless, you aren't even comparing apples with apples.  Your `Rf_eval` example *does not pass the vector* to the function, and, more importantly, plays tricks on the function via `quote()`.

In short, it is all a little silly.

Below is a more complete example using the sugar function `mean()`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List callFun(Function fun, NumericVector vec) {
  List output(1000);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    output[i] = fun(NumericVector(vec));
  }
  return output;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List callRfEval(SEXP fun, SEXP env){
  List output(1000);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    output[i] = Rf_eval(fun, env);
  }
  return output;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List callSugar(NumericVector vec) {
  List output(1000);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    double d = mean(vec);
    output[i] = d;
  }
  return output;
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(callFun(mean, 1:1000),   
               callRfEval(quote(mean(1:1000)), .GlobalEnv),
               callSugar(1:1000))
*/
```

You can just `sourceCpp()` this:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/ch.cpp")

R> library(microbenchmark)

R> microbenchmark(callFun(mean, 1:1000), 
+                callRfEval(quote(mean(1:1000)), .GlobalEnv),
+                callSugar(1:1000))
Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
                       callFun(mean, 1:1000) 14.87451 15.54385 18.57635 17.78990 18.29127 114.77153   100
 callRfEval(quote(mean(1:1000)), .GlobalEnv)  3.35954  3.57554  3.97380  3.75122  4.16450   6.29339   100
                           callSugar(1:1000)  1.50061  1.50827  1.62204  1.51518  1.76683   1.84513   100
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk,

As mentioned in another comment, sugar does not suit my needs, I am trying to implement a generic apply across files. I also am not quite sure I understand how quoted expression is playing tricks on the function, and how it gets around passing the function and argument. Does Rf_eval not evaluate the expression?

Comment: Let's just agree to disagree about scope and aim here.